# Method is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have a piece of JS code in for loop:

```
window.gamesParse = {
    days: days,
    dates: dates,
    times: times,
    series: series,
    homes: homes,
    aways: aways,
    channels: channels
}

var image = $.get("assets/images/" + gamesParse.aways[i] + ".png");
if (image.status !== 404) {
    console.dir(image);
} else {
    console.dir(image);
}
```

Now, it returns the right Objects which have `status` property. But if I change `image` to `image.status` (or any other property or method), it returns undefined.
Is it normal? How can I access `status` property from there?

Comment: Its okay! then what is the question? Do you want any answer for it? it is undefined because status property is not available in it.

Comment: @Jai I thought the undefined situation was not expected. question edited.

Comment: Newbie error. Javascript is _asynchronous_. You have to wait for the `get` function to finish and come back with the result, before testing `image.status`. Use a callback function. `$.get("png", function(image){ console.log(image); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal because `$.get` is asynchronous, which in this current code means that it **loads** data. But on the very next line you ask about the status of the image, which in fact is still loading. What you have to do is wait for the image to load, and then check the code. Something like:

```
$.get("assets/images/" + gamesParse.aways[i] + ".png", function(image) {
    // here image can have status
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`image` is undefined because it's out of the get action, try to put it into a callback function. Like this:

```
$.get("assets/images/" + gamesParse.aways[i] + ".png", function(response) {
   if (response.status !== 404) {
        // do stuff here
    } else {
        // or here
    } 
});
```

Check the **[docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**.